# Why does Puppeteer sometimes get a blank snapshot even though I set essential data and I18n text before starting the page?

Tags: puppeteer

Puppeteer get blank snapshot sometimes, I set the esstienal data and I18n text with session before i start the page each time. but the intresting things it is that sometime it can't get all page content, some parts are blank. already set the timeout and ideltype . all case cant resolve the issues.

puppeteer: 18.1.0
node: 16.20.0
npm: 8.19.5

Front-End:
Angular 14

any suggestion with it ?

give me more suggestion, what is should be do for next dig.

Comment: Hard to say without a runnable [mcve] of the code.